# Fetch Casted Value from a select query into an array

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server, database, casting

I used cast in order to convert a datatype of one of the columns in my select query.

```
SELECT cast(user_id as varchar(255)) from cabinet
```

I need to fetch the result of this value into an array but it returns null value

```
$listData[] = array(
    "member_id" => $row['cast(user_id]
  );
```

How can I display it on array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT cast(user_id AS varchar(255)) AS member_id FROM cabinet
```

PHP:

```
$listData = array("member_id" => $row['member_id']);
```

Basically, you forgot to name the cast function's return in your SQL and used some extremely weird syntax in your PHP. `$Array[] = $x;` adds element `$x` as an array item to `$Array` in PHP. To create a new array, you should run `$Array = array();`. Some programming languages do indeed force you to put square brackets after a variable's name on value assignation to specify it as an Array/String type, but PHP is not one of them.

To reference an item by key, you have to use the array's name and the key's value in square brackets (`$Array[$n]`, where `$n` is an integer for arrays with integer indexes, and `Array['key']` for arrays with String indexes). `'cast(user_id AS varchar(255))'` is not a valid array key, you have to give the SQL function return value a name to be able to reference it as an array item.

Please let me know if this makes sense.

My answer assumes that you are familiar with [`mySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and know how to get `$row['member_id']` from the query.